# Leading Order Behaviour using Watson and Laplace

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory, laplace-method

> Find the leading order behaviour of $$I(x)=\int_0^1 \sin te^{-x\sinh^4 t}dt, \enspace x\rightarrow\infty$$ Thus evaluate $I(10)$ and compare it with its numerical value $I(10)\approx0.13564$

So far, I have defined $f(t)=\sin t$ and $g(t)=-\sinh^4 t$ so that I can use Laplace's Method. Then, to find where $g(t)_{\max}$ occurs, $g'(t)=-4\sinh^3 t\cosh t=0$ and so $t=0$. (Also it should be noted that we have been introduced to Laplace's Method as an application of Watson's Lemma only, where we can disregard the non-local contributions as we have proved they are non-dominant.)

I have been given the following fact that I can use:

> If $g(t)$ achieves its maximum value $g(t)_{\max}=\max_{a \leq t\leq b}g(t)$ at a set of points in the interval of integration $[a,b]$, then let $c_i$ denote the points where the maximum is achieved (for $i=1,...,N)$. Laplace's method shows that if $g''(c_i)<0$ for all $i$, then \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> I(x) &= \int_a^be^{xg(t)}f(t)dt \\
> & = e^{xg_{\max}} \left( x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^N \sqrt \frac{2\pi}{-g''(c_i)}f(c_i)+O(x^{-1}) \right) \enspace x\rightarrow\infty
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation} Where $O(x^{-1})$ represents the Big-Oh notation.

Seeing as I know that $c=0$, when I substitute this $c$ value into $g''(t)=-4\sinh^4t-12\sinh^2t\cosh^2t$, I get $g''(0)=0$. However, this throws up issues since using the rule above, I would have $g''(c=0)=0$ as a denominator.

Have I misinterpreted the question, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the change of variables $t = \operatorname{arcsinh} \sqrt u$ to reduce the integral to the standard case. Essentially, this holds:
$$\int_0^1 e^{-x \sinh^4 t} \sin t\,dt \sim
\int_0^\infty e^{-x t^4} t \,dt =
\frac 1 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-x (t^2)^2} d(t^2).$$

Comment: Are you using the fact that $t$ can be a dummy variable?

Comment: The last step just shows how the integral of $t e^{-x t^4}$ can be evaluated (with the change of variables $t^2 = \xi$, since $d(t^2) = 2t dt$). The change of variables $t = \operatorname{arcsinh} \sqrt u$ in your original integral will also give a function which is regular and non-zero at $u = 0$ times $e^{-x u^2}$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Thank you!